# Is it possible to get selected index page of DetailsView control in Page_Load method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have DetailsView control, with enabled paging.

When I select another page in DetailsView control, postback accrued and Page_Load method fired.

I need to get the selected index page.

Any idea how can I get selected index page of DetailsView control in Page_Load method?

Comment: Can you share a bit of source code ? It can be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I know how is to check the form post in your Page_load. something like this:

```
if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] == detailsView1.UniqueID)
{
    int reqPage;
    if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Replace("Page$", string.Empty), out reqPage))
    {
        // do something with that requested page, but remember to -1
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please briefly explain why I get in Request.Form["__EVENTARGUMENT"] this: Page$+someIndex what is meaning of Page$?

Comment: It's ASP's way of uniquely identifying the page number. I'm assuming it was just a design decision that was made.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ASP.NET page life cycle:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Post back events are handled after PageLoad. I would go with subscribing to

```
DetailsView.PageIndexChanging
```

event:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.detailsview.pageindexchanging(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I need to get Index inside Page_load method